# Вывод текущего месяца, задваиваются цифры на php

Tags: php, циклы, условия

Всем добрый вечер!
Нужно вывести месяц, выходные отметить красным, текущую дату обвести.
При выводе удваиваются цифры. Подскажите, в чем причина?
Заранее спасибо.

```
<style> 
.normal:hover {
    background-color: black; 
    color: white;
} 
.weekend:hover {
    background-color: red; 
    color: white;
}


</style>

<?php

echo "<table><tbody><tr>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
    echo '<td class="normal" style="color:black" normal:hover">'.$i."</td>";
    
    if ($i == 7 || $i == 14 || $i == 21 || $i == 28) {
        echo '<td class="weekend" style="color:red">'.($i-1)."</td>";
        echo '<td class="weekend" style="color:red">'.$i."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
    
    if ($i == date(j)) {
        echo '<td style="border:1px solid blue">'.$i."</td>";
    }
}
echo "</tbody></table>";


?>
```

Comment: ну так если вы выводите ячейку на каждой итерации, а потом выводите повторно на 7-14... по два выходных, и текущий, который генерит нотис, ибо неизвестная константа, конечно оно будет  повторяться.

Comment: Переделала, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как можно делать календарь и не использовать DateTime?

```
<style>
        .month {
            width: 350px;
            display: block;
        }
        .month .day {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50px;
            border: #0000ff 1px solid;
            padding: 5px;
            color: #1a4580;
        }
        .month .day.today {
            color: white !important;
            background-color: green !important;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .month .day.invis {
            border: none;

        }
        .month .day.weekend {
            color: red;
            border: red 1px solid;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="month">
<?php
    $dt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    $day = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '01.' . $dt->format('m.Y'));
    $dayOfWeek = 1;
    while ($dayOfWeek < $day->format('N')) {
        ?><div class="day invis <?=($day->format('N') > 5 ? 'weekend' : '');?>"></div><?
        $dayOfWeek++;
    }

    while ($day->format('m') == $dt->format('m')) {
        ?><div class="day <?=($day->format('N') > 5 ? 'weekend' : '');?><?=($day->format('d') == $dt->format('d') ? ' today' : '');?>"><?=$day->format('d');?></div><?
        $day = $day->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

[image: календарь]

Answer (score 0):

Календарь на текущий месяц

```
<?php
$offset = getWeekDay(1) - 1;
$rowNum = (int)((date('t') + $offset) / 7) + 1;

function getWeekDay($day) {
    return date('N', strtotime(date('Y-m-' . $day)));
}

function getCssClass($day) {
    if (getWeekDay($day) >= 6 ) {
        $cssClass = 'weekend';
    }
    else {
        $cssClass = 'normal';
    }
    if ($day == date('j')) {
        $cssClass .= ' today';
    }
    return $cssClass;
}
?>

<style>
    .normal {
        color:black;
    }
    .weekend {
        color:red;
    }
    .today {
        border:1px solid blue;
    }
</style>

<?= date('d-m-Y') ?>
<table><tbody>
    <?php for ($row = 0; $row < $rowNum; $row++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <?php for ($dayWeek = 1; $dayWeek <= 7; $dayWeek++) { ?>
                <?php $day = $row * 7 + $dayWeek - $offset; ?>
                <?php if ($day > 0 && $day <= date('t')) { ?>
                    <td class="<?= getCssClass($day) ?>"><?= $day ?></td>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <td></td>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот, что получилось.
Коряво, что 2 условия на 6 и на 7.

```
    echo "<table><tbody><tr>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
    
    
    if ($i == 7 || $i == 14 || $i == 21 || $i == 28) {
        echo '<td class="weekend" style="color:red">'.$i."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } elseif ($i == 6 || $i == 13 || $i == 20 || $i == 27) {
        echo '<td class="weekend" style="color:red">'.$i."</td>";
    } elseif ($i == date(j)) {
        echo '<td style="border:1px solid blue">'.$i."</td>";
    } else {
        echo '<td class="normal" style="color:black" normal:hover">'.$i."</td>";
    }
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: для определения 7-14-21 и т.д. можно проверить что остаток от деления на 7 = 0. Вообще календарь весьма условный, поскольку не каждый месяц имеет 31 день и начинается с понедельника, скорее ситуация довольно редкая. и `date(j)` следует замеменить на `date('j')` и вообще включить отображение ошибок пхп.

Comment: а вооще надо просто в начале цикла опредить, какой день выходной или текущий. и сформировать класс. напримре `$isWeekend = $i%7==0` потом `$isCurrent = $i == date('j')`. Потом определить класс `$cls = "";` и добавить туда нужное вида `if($isWeekend) $cls .= "weekend"`  и т.п. а в заключении вывеси `<?= "<td class="$cls">$i</td>"?>` и все. Чем больше вы отделите логику от представления, тем лучше.